# Is it possible/meaningful to have a right triangle with sides $0$, $1$, and $i$?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, triangles

If $i^2 = -1$, does that mean you could have a triangle with side lengths $0$, $1$, and $i$?  But if you draw such as triangle on a complex number grid, the hypotenuse length is $\sqrt 2$, not $0$.  Does the pythagorean theorem only apply to real numbers?

Comment: A triangle with side $0$ in itself is a "problem" irrespective of $i$

Comment: @qazwsx: A length of $0$ isn't so much a "problem" as a *degeneracy*; indeed, even *negative* lengths (and areas, and etc) have their uses. *Imaginary* lengths are trickier to wrap one's brain around (mine is not yet properly wrapped), but occasionally they come in handy, if only as a matter of notational expediency (eg, thinking of hyperbolic geometry as geometry on a sphere imaginary radius). I believe a question was asked here recently about the geometry of imaginary lengths (with an answer or comment giving what may have been a useful reference), but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

No.

That wouldn't be possible because distance is inherently a nonnegative real number, usually -- you can see this in the formal definition of a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition), which is how we define distance in a mathematically rigorous and formal sense.

Within that framework, then, it's not possible to have negative distances, much less complex ones. For instance, we can define the distance between the complex numbers $0,i,1$ by the usual "Euclidean distance" or "$2$-metric", the distance you're familiar with. But for complex numbers, this ties back somewhat to definition of magnitude. We define the distance $d(z_1,z_2)$ between complex numbers $z$ (under this metric) to be

$$d(z_1,z_2) = |z_1-z_2|$$

where $| \cdot |$ denotes magnitude. Notice how this is a real number (magnitudes of complex numbers always are). In fact, if $z_i = x_i + i y_i$ for $i=1,2$, then

$$d(z_1,z_2) = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2}$$

What this all says is that it is nonsense to say that a side length can have length "$i$". This is because what you're ultimately, truly meaning is "what is the distance between $0$ and $i$ in the complex plane (under a certain metric)?" Yes, $0+i=i$, but that distance is meant to be measured in terms of nonnegative, real numbers -- otherwise, the distance between $-2$ and $0$ is $-2$, which doesn't make sense.

Or in a different sense, perhaps bear in mind the difference between "distance/length" and "displacement."